# Aligment of textbox in proportion to the text

Tags: html, css, alignment

How do I correct the following E-mail textbox alignment: ?

[image]

To make it look like this:

[image]

I know I can use tables, but how do I solve this problem without using tables? CSS maybe?

HTML:

```
<form action="" name="contactform" method="post">
<p></p>
First name: <input type="text" class="contact" name="contactfirstname" value="">
<br/>
Last name: <input type="text" class="contact" name="contactlastname" value="">
<br/>
E-mail: <input type="text" class="contact" name="email" value="">
<p></p>
```

Comment: Please provide your HTML code, as the CSS code depends on your markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[The most minimalized version I could think of...](http://jsfiddle.net/eRGYx/)**

```
<form>
    <label>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName"></label>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName"></label>
    <label>Email Address: <input type="email" name="emailAddress"></label>
</form>​
```

and

```
form {
    width: 300px;
}
label {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    clear: both;
}
label input {
    float: right;
}​
```

---

Since OP has edited his question to include his markup, I'll expand the answer.

### Some Points of Improvement:

- Remove the empty `<p>` element, and the `<br/>` elements. They have no value inside a form.
- Use `<label>`s, that's what they were made for. You can wrap the label **and** the input inside of the `<label>` tag, or you can use `<label for="element_id">Label</label><input id="element_id">`.
- Be consistent. If you decided to go with the `<br />` type of format for singular tags, stick with it to the `<input />`s as well.
- Use correct input types for specific inputs, there is `type="email"` for the email field, which will optionally have the browser check for you if it's a valid email address or not!.
- Use CSS for design and layout, not `<p>`s and `<br>`s.

Good luck!

Comment: I get why I should avoid the <p> tags but without the <br/> tags, how would you newline the labels/textboxes?

Comment: Setting `display: block` on the label does that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your HTML is something like:

```
<p>
   Email
   <input />
</p>
```

Change this to:

```
<p>
   <label>Email</label>
   <input />
</p>
```

This means you can then apply a fixed width to all your labels, making them consistent:

```
label
{
width:100px;
float:left;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/zvWqk/1/**

---

Or as @Zeta has pointed out, nest your input inside the label, and float right. This will prevent you needing to apply a `for` attribute to your label.

http://jsfiddle.net/tt8gx/

Comment: Or apply a fixed with on `<p>` and use `float:right` on the input, so you can still provide the semantic information on label without using `for=inputID` (http://jsfiddle.net/tt8gx/).

Comment: Using `<p>` elements as form labels is not a healthy thing to do. Not from the semantic nor the usability point of view. Paragraphs are meant to be paragraphs, of text. Using labels and perhaps an unordered list seems more appropriate, though it can be solved even without the list.

Comment: @Truth Cheers, I wasn't aware of that. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to make the labels display as block elements and have a fixed width. Display the inputs as block elements and float them left. Put a `clear:left` on the labels so they'll each be on a new line.

Comment: When elements are floated, the `display` property on the is ignored (floats have their own display values, like "`display: float`").

Comment: Fancy that, I didn't think you could float inline elements. Thanks.

Comment: Floats were **meant** for inline elements, to float images inside text and allow the text to flow around them. :)